# Duplicar pestañas en Visual Studio 2022

Tags: visual-studio

Alguien conoce una forma de duplicar las pestañas en el Visual Studio, tal como se puede hacer en el VSCode?

Adjunto pantalla de este último para dejar clara la pregunta

[image: VSCode]

En la imagen, el documento mostrado es el mismo y cualquier cambio se ve reflejado en ambas vistas.

Estoy casi seguro de que no se puede, pero quizá alguien me sorprende!

Gracias a todos!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ventana > Nueva Ventana. Después pincha en la nueva pestaña y arrastrala hasta el medio de la ventana, aparecerá un selector de opciones para anclarla en vertical u horizontal